# HTML5 video player is blank and GET error appears in output console

Tags: html, video, get, console, mp4

I'm trying to play a video in a  tag on a plain html page. I have a video in Premiere which i have tried to export both as webm and mp4 (h264) which is located in the same directory on the FTP server as the html file. No matter which codec i render in, the player stays blank (white) and GET errors appear in the output console:

[GET Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNrrA.png)

As you can see the video files are clearly in the same directory on the FTP server:

[Files on FTP server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSYLy.png)

The GET error has been replaced with a 404 error sometimes when using different presets with both webm and h264. As far as i know webm and h264 are especially suited for html5 web-players, adobe has tons of different presets, so I really don't get why this has to be such a tricky problem to solve. It is impossible to find someone else with the same problem and this irritates me even more.

We use Azure as web hosting, so if there are any default setting prohibiting video display or similar, tell me!

[EDIT]: Here's the html code for **video_presentation.html**:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
  <source src="course_introduction.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="course_introduction.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

PLEASE HELP!
And thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using another browser? I know I had to detect Chrome and in-case of Chrome detected only use the webm source.

Comment: Also, tried using an online URL as source to check? Because then you could limit your problem to the `src=""` only if it works. Examples: `http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm` and `http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4`

Comment: What are the actual error messages?

Comment: can you open the video (eg the .mp4 in Chrome) with just a URL. does the URL match what's in the HTML?

Comment: @AlgernopK. No I could not play the video directly from an URL. The page was blank and default text stated: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.". The file DOES exists so the only viable option is that it is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

For multiple video clips as you have mentioned above, for maximum HTML5 video browser compatibility you need to make 3 different versions of your video. You can embed multiple HTML5 videos into web pages in a HTML5 video element, below is the HTML5 Video markup example for multiple videos:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
   <source src="ftp or http://path/course_introduction.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="ftp or http://path/course_introduction.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="ftp or http://path/course_introduction.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

enjoy!!!

Comment: I see your point, have to get third party converter in the meantime. But is it required to have at least 3, or is it just a norm speaking of coding and support. Because if Chrome can't play the .mp4 and there is no minimum requirement for HTML5 video then I might be back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the mime types to the sites .htaccess file:

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v
AddType audio/mp4 m4a
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType audio/ogg ogg oga
AddType video/webm webm
```